# Comparing a column using the data of one column in the same table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

I have a table with two columns, name and numb. The first column contains a name and the second contains a number for that name.

What I'm trying to do is output 3 columns, name, number, name, where the last name column is a name that contains the same number as the first name column.

So the output would probably look like this:

```
 | NAME | NUMB | NAME |
 |------|------|------|
 | john |    1 | lucy |
 | stan |    2 | paul |
 | jane |    3 | bill |
```

etc.

I have an sqlfiddle link here of the table I'm using: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed72b/1

I'm doing this in MySQL. Thank you.

Comment: `is a name that contains the same number` => I just don't understand that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a `JOIN` on the same table, like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.numb, t2.name AS name2
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.numb = t2.numb AND t1.name <> t2.name
```

See it [live](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed72b/20)!

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work however how would I prevent duplicates being seen?

Comment: You need to find a way to uniquely identify rows. For example, you can add `WHERE t1.name < t2.name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT name FROM test tt WHERE tt.numb = t.numb AND tt.name <> t.name limit 1) nname
from test t;
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed72b/21)

The problem with your idea, can be seen when looking at the second set of rows

```
 | NAME | NUMB | NAME |
 |------|------|------|
 | paul |    1 | stan |
 | bill |    2 | jane |
 | lucy |    3 | john |
```

which is the reverse of the first rows. How do you determine to use the first 3, and not the last 3?

Answer (score 1):

This query will work, "SELECT t1.name,t1.numb,t2.name as newnumb from test as t1, test as t2 where t1.numb = t2.numb AND t1.name != t2.name;"

but it will give you output as

```
NAME    NUMB    NEWNUMB

lucy    1        john

paul    2        stan

bill    3        jane

stan    2        paul

jane    3        bill

john    1        lucy
```

because if the numb of lucky is 1, its 1 for john also, so it will return two different rows, which is correct.

Hope this helps you.